# "'h' must be bound in every pattern" error in switch statement

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching

What is the cause of this error in the switch statement?

> 'h' must be bound in every pattern

I'm basically trying to use h as a variable for hour, make sure that it isn't nil (because hour is initially an optional value, and then see if it's greater than 17).

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: date as Date)
let hour = components.hour

switch hour {
case let h, (h as Int) != nil, h >= 17:
    return true
default:
    return false        
}
```

Comment: As this doesn't seem to be using pattern matching, you may want to throw that in an if statement instead.

Comment: I did throw it into an if-statement in the end, but why do you suggest that? My attempt here was to create an optional binding with let, so that 'h' would be the unwrapped value of Optional(hour)

Comment: The comma in `case` statements means `OR`, not `AND`. You can't use a comma with a declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to write something like this:

```
switch hour {
case let h? where h >= 17:
    return true
default:
    return false

}
```

Or, as suggested, using `if` statement:

```
if let h = hour, h >= 17 {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

Or else, simply:

```
return hour != nil && hour! >= 17
```

---

The error message is often found in this pattern:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case patternA(Int)
    case patternB(Int)
    case patternC
}

let me = MyEnum.patternB(30)

switch me {
case .patternA(let h), .patternB(let h), .patternC: //<-
    print("A or B with h, or C")
default:
    print("this may never happen")
}
```

Comment: The first example, using case let h?... That's the one I'm looking for!!! How come this works? Why are you declaring h as an optional with the question mark? How come when I remove the question mark after h, the compiler wants me to force unwrap the h in the 'where' clause? Thanks

Comment: @user7024499, question mark in case pattern like `let h?` is a short cut form of `.some(let h)`. In Swift, Optional values are enum values like `.some(someValue)` or `.none`, so `.some(let h)` matches to the non-Optional value.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean let h? is a short cut form of .some(h)? As opposed to 'let H'. I may be wrong, but that just makes more sense to me. That portrays than the optional enum is holding a value of 'h', which is being set equal to the actual value of the unwrapped value of 'hour', in which case, the where clause supports the use of h to be an actual value and not a wrapped value.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this when I got the same error:

```
case .something, .other(let parameter) where parameter != nil:
     doSomething()
```

I think, Swift 5 can't handle such complicated expressions, so I had to split it:

```
case .something:
     fallthrough
case .other(let parameter) where parameter != nil:
     doSomething()
```

Check [fallthrough operator reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow/#Fallthrough) for more details, but it basically is used to continue execution to next case